# Can't Access Kubernetes Service Exposed via NodePort

Tags: docker, kubernetes, namespaces, minikube

I'm using minikube to test kubernetes on latest MacOS.

Here are my relevant YAMLs:

**namespace.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: micro
  labels:
    name: micro
```

**deployment.yml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: adderservice
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: adderservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: adderservice
        image: jeromesoung/adderservice:0.0.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

**service.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: adderservice
  labels:
    run: adderservice
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      name: main
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: adderservice
  type: NodePort
```

After running `minikube start`, the steps I took to deploy is as follows:

1. `kubectl create -f namespace.yml` to create the namespace
2. `kubectl config set-context minikube --namespace=micro`
3. `kubectl create -f deployment.yml`
4. `kubectl create -f service.yml`

Then, I get the NodeIP and NodePort with below commands:

1. `kubectl get services` to get the NodePort

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME           TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
adderservice   NodePort   10.99.155.255   <none>        8080:30981/TCP   21h
```

2. `minikube ip` to get the nodeIP

```
$ minikube ip
192.168.99.103
```

But when I do curl, I always get **Connection Refused** like this:

```
$ curl http://192.168.99.103:30981/add/1/2
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.103 port 30981: Connection refused
```

So I checked node, pod, deployment and endpoint as follows:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
minikube   Ready     master    23h       v1.13.3

$ kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
adderservice-5b567df95f-9rrln   1/1       Running   0          23h

$ kubectl get deployments
NAME           DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
adderservice   1         1         1            1           23h

$ kubectl get endpoints
NAME           ENDPOINTS         AGE
adderservice   172.17.0.5:8080   21h
```

I also checked service list from minikube with:

```
$ minikube service -n micro adderservice --url
http://192.168.99.103:30981
```

I've read many posts regarding accessing k8s service via NodePorts. To my knowledge, I should be able to access the app with no problem. The only thing I suspect is that I'm using a custom namespace. Will this cause the access issue?

I know namespace will change the DNS, so, to be complete, I ran below commands also:

```
$ kubectl exec -ti adderservice-5b567df95f-9rrln -- nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.0.1

$ kubectl exec -ti adderservice-5b567df95f-9rrln -- nslookup kubernetes.micro
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   kubernetes.micro
Address: 198.105.244.130
Name:   kubernetes.micro
Address: 104.239.207.44
```

Could anyone help me out? Thank you.

Comment: Is this a custom image ? and do you face the same issue on docker ?

Comment: Yes, this is my docker image just for testing purpose. There's no issue when barely running in docker containers on my local.

Comment: what is the value of `ADDERSERVICE_SERVICE_HOST` ?

Comment: In this case, it's defaulted to [::] according to the output of netstat

Comment: can you manually assign it to be `0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: Awesome, I manually defined the two env variables via the deployment YAML. And the app is statically made run on 0.0.0.0:8080 And I can access it from outside now. So, for application/service I want to expose to outside, do I have to manually assign host and port to it? Is there a way to use the YAML to define it? I thought that's what the environment variables injected by K8S are used for...

Comment: Yes you have to inject them manually AFAIK. I have updated the answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error `Connection Refused` mostly means that the application inside the container does not accept requests on the targeted interface or not mapped through the expected ports.

Things you need to be aware of:

- Make sure that your application bind to `0.0.0.0` so it can receive requests from outside the container either externally as in public or through other containers.
- Make sure that your application is actually listening on the `containerPort` and `targetPort` as expect

In your case you have to make sure that `ADDERSERVICE_SERVICE_HOST` equals to `0.0.0.0` and `ADDERSERVICE_SERVICE_PORT` equals to `8080` which should be the same value as `targetPort` in `service.yml` and `containerPort` in `deployment.yml`

Comment: Hi @Mostafa I'm having a similar issue where it appears that NodePort is only listening via IPv6: `netstat -al | grep 30036` outputs only: `tcp6  0  0 [::]:30036  [::]:*  LISTEN` - I wonder if you would be able to be more general in how to bind the app to `0.0.0.0` so that it will become available via an IPv4 address (i.e.the node ip of the application)? The solution given seems specific to the config for @XXXXX The app is correctly deployed otherwise and is running in the container. It cannot be accessed via `curl` or a browser, the result is simply a timeout or connection refused.

Comment: Thanks, my app was binding to 127.0.0.1 instead of 0.0.0.0 :)

Answer (score 4):

Not answering the question but if someone who googled comes here like me who faced the same issue. Here is my solution for the same problem.

My Mac System IP and minikube IP are different.

So localhost:port didn't work instead try getting IP

`minikube ip`

Later, use that IP:Port to access the app and it works.

Comment: thankyou, I try to use localhost instead of minikube ip, but with minikube ip works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Check if service is really listening on 8080.

Try telnet within the container.

```sh
telnet 127.0.0.1 8080
.
.
.
telnet 172.17.0.5 8080
```

Comment: No. After checking using netstat, I can see the app is listening on 38641...
`
root@adderservice-5b567df95f-9rrln:/home/node/service# netstat -ltnpau
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 :::38641                :::*                    LISTEN      1/node
`