# Kubernetes deployment not reachable via browser exposed with service

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm following below to launch a multi-container app (db and web-app). Following is based on [this](https://github.com/markz0r/eramba-community-docker).

--- BLOW STEPS ARE COPIED FROM ANSWER PROVIDED BY [THIS USER](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14704799/gohmc) [docker mysql in kuberneted ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '' (-3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70626198/docker-mysql-in-kuberneted-error-2005-hy000-unknown-mysql-server-host-3/70631467?noredirect=1#comment124872192_70631467) ---

First, use your favorite editor to start a eramba-cm.yaml file:

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: eramba
  namespace: eramba-1
data:
  c2.8.1.sql: |
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS erambadb;
    USE erambadb;
    ## IMPORTANT: MUST BE INDENT 2 SPACES AFTER c2.8.1.sql ##
    <copy & paste content from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markz0r/eramba-community-docker/master/sql/c2.8.1.sql>
```

---

```
kubectl create -f eramba-cm.yaml
```

Create the storage for MariaDB:

```
    cat << EOF > eramba-storage.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: eramba-storage
spec:
  storageClassName: eramba-storage
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes: 
  - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /home/osboxes/eramba/erambadb
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: eramba-storage
  namespace: eramba-1
spec:
  storageClassName: eramba-storage
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
...
EOF
```

---

```
kubectl create -f eramba-storage.yaml
```

Install bitnami/mariadb using Helm

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
helm upgrade -i eramba bitnami/mariadb --set auth.rootPassword=eramba,auth.database=erambadb,initdbScriptsConfigMap=eramba,volumePermissions.enabled=true,primary.persistence.existingClaim=eramba-storage --namespace eramba-1 --set mariadb.volumePermissions.enabled=true
```

Run eramba web application:

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: eramba-web
  namespace: eramba-1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: eramba-web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eramba-web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eramba-web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: eramba-web
        image: markz0r/eramba-app:c281
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_HOSTNAME
          value: eramba-mariadb
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: erambadb
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          value: root
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          value: eramba
        - name: DATABASE_PREFIX
          value: ""
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eramba-web
  namespace: eramba-1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: eramba-web
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 30045
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: eramba-web
  type: NodePort
...
```

Now browse eramba-web via `port-forward` or `http://<node ip>:30045`.

The `kubectl get cm,pvc,pv,svc,pods` output is:

```
root@osboxes:~# kubectl get cm,pvc,pv,svc,pods -o wide -n eramba-1
NAME                         DATA   AGE
configmap/eramba             1      134m
configmap/eramba-mariadb     1      131m
configmap/kube-root-ca.crt   1      29h

NAME                                   STATUS   VOLUME           CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS     AGE    VOLUMEMODE
persistentvolumeclaim/eramba-storage   Bound    eramba-storage   5Gi        RWO            eramba-storage   133m   Filesystem

NAME                              CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                     STORAGECLASS     REASON   AGE    VOLUMEMODE
persistentvolume/eramba-storage   5Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    eramba-1/eramba-storage   eramba-storage            133m   Filesystem

NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE    SELECTOR
service/eramba-mariadb   ClusterIP   10.104.161.85   <none>        3306/TCP         131m   app.kubernetes.io/component=primary,app.kubernetes.io/instance=eramba,app.kubernetes.io/name=mariadb
service/eramba-web       NodePort    10.100.185.75   <none>        8080:30045/TCP   129m   app.kubernetes.io/name=eramba-web

NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP          NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/eramba-mariadb-0              1/1     Running   0          131m   10.20.0.6   osboxes   <none>           <none>
pod/eramba-web-6cc9c687d8-k6r9j   1/1     Running   0          129m   10.20.0.7   osboxes   <none>           <none>
```

When I tried to access `10.100.185.75:30045`, the browser is says not reachable.

```
root@osboxes:/home/osboxes/eramba# kubectl describe service/eramba-web -n eramba-1
Name:                     eramba-web
Namespace:                eramba-1
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/name=eramba-web
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/name=eramba-web
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.100.185.75
IPs:                      10.100.185.75
Port:                     http  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30045/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
```

the logs for the web-app pod:

```
root@osboxes:~# kubectl logs eramba-web-6cc9c687d8-k6r9j -n eramba-1
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.20.0.7. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
root@osboxes:~#
```

I've noticed the lack of endpoint for the Eramba-web service. When I changed the selector app to `eramba-web`, the endpoint has an IP, but the browser still cant reach the app.

Comment: A `NodePort` service is exposed on the ip addresses of cluster nodes.  The `10.100.x.y` address is an internal address you won't be able to access.

Comment: ahhh I see. How would I fix this?

Comment: By using the ip address of one of the kubernetes nodes instead of that 10.100 address (or exposing the service using an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) instead).

Comment: lol I'm dumb. It's the IP returned by kubectl get nodes -o yaml

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't know I couldn't do that :( - your answer was awesome! I planned to edit it and promote as answer. Sorry I will credit you in this post.

Comment: the reason why I didn't link you was because I modified the namespace and pod deployment btw. I figured it would be easier for the readers to read the new yaml instead of saying "I added namespace" in case it was my yaml files acting up

Answer (score 0):

*This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.*

The requester uses the NodePort type for the `eramba-web` service. To access the application, it necessary to use the IP addresses of the nodes in the cluster, instead of using the internal IP address `10.100.x.y`.

From [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types):

> NodePort: Exposes the Service on each Node's IP at a static port (the
> NodePort). A ClusterIP Service, to which the NodePort Service routes,
> is automatically created. You'll be able to contact the NodePort
> Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting <NodeIP>:<NodePort>.