# Accessing via NodeIP:NodePort returns connection refused

Tags: kubernetes

I created by cluster by using `echo 'KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS="--network-plugin=kubenet --pod-cidr=10.20.0.0/24 --pod-infra-container-image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6"' > /etc/default/kubelet`. The setup is ran in a ubuntu VM using NAT configurations.

There is one cluster partitioned with two namespaces, each with one deployment of an application instance (think one application for one client). I'm trying to access the individual application instance via nodeIP:nodePort. I can access the application via ; however, this way I cant access application belonging to client A and client B separately.

If you're interested in the exact steps taken, see [Kubernetes deployment not reachable via browser exposed with service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70637470/kubernetes-deployment-not-reachable-via-browser-exposed-with-service?noredirect=1#comment124871687_70637470)

Below is the yaml file for deployment in eramba-1 namespace (so for the second deployment, I just have namespace = eramba-2)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: eramba-web
  namespace: eramba-1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: eramba-web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eramba-web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eramba-web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: eramba-web
        image: markz0r/eramba-app:c281
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_HOSTNAME
          value: eramba-mariadb
        - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: erambadb
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          value: root
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          value: eramba
        - name: DATABASE_PREFIX
          value: ""
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eramba-web
  namespace: eramba-1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: eramba-web
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: eramba-web
  type: NodePort
...
```

Service output for eramba-1 namespace

```
root@osboxes:/home/osboxes/eramba# kubectl describe svc eramba-web -n eramba-1
Name:                     eramba-web
Namespace:                eramba-1
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/name=eramba-web
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/name=eramba-web
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.100.17.120
IPs:                      10.100.17.120
Port:                     http  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32370/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Service for eramba-2 output

```
root@osboxes:/home/osboxes/eramba# kubectl describe svc eramba-web2 -n eramba-2
    Name:                     eramba-web2
    Namespace:                eramba-2
    Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/name=eramba-web2
    Annotations:              <none>
    Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/name=eramba-web2
    Type:                     NodePort
    IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
    IP Families:              IPv4
    IP:                       10.98.240.243
    IPs:                      10.98.240.243
    Port:                     http  8080/TCP
    TargetPort:               8080/TCP
    NodePort:                 http  32226/TCP
    Endpoints:                <none>
    Session Affinity:         None
    External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
    Events:                   <none>
```

I've verified the nodePorts listening status

```
root@osboxes:/home/osboxes/eramba# netstat -tunlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      **0 0.0.0.0:32370**           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3776/kube-proxy     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10259         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3476/kube-scheduler 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      535/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      587/cupsd           
tcp        0      **0 0.0.0.0:32226**           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3776/kube-proxy     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10248         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2983/kubelet        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10249         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3776/kube-proxy     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      809/mysqld          
tcp        0      0 172.16.42.135:2379      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3495/etcd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3495/etcd           
tcp        0      0 172.16.42.135:2380      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3495/etcd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2381          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3495/etcd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:39469         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2983/kubelet        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10257         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3521/kube-controlle 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      587/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      809/mysqld          
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      2983/kubelet        
tcp6       0      0 :::6443                 :::*                    LISTEN      3485/kube-apiserver 
tcp6       0      0 :::10256                :::*                    LISTEN      3776/kube-proxy     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      729/apache2         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:35922           0.0.0.0:*                           589/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           589/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           535/systemd-resolve 
udp        0      0 172.16.42.135:68        0.0.0.0:*                           586/NetworkManager  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           654/cups-browsed    
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                589/avahi-daemon: r 
udp6       0      0 :::37750                :::*                                589/avahi-daemon: r
```

Here's the Iptables output

```
root@osboxes:/home/osboxes/eramba# iptables --list-rules
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-N KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-N KUBE-FIREWALL
-N KUBE-FORWARD
-N KUBE-KUBELET-CANARY
-N KUBE-NODEPORTS
-N KUBE-PROXY-CANARY
-N KUBE-SERVICES
-A INPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes health check service ports" -j KUBE-NODEPORTS
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A INPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -j KUBE-FORWARD
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES -p tcp -m comment --comment "eramba-2/eramba-web2:http has no endpoints" -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -m tcp --dport 32226 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES -p tcp -m comment --comment "eramba-1/eramba-web:http has no endpoints" -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -m tcp --dport 32370 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A KUBE-FIREWALL -m comment --comment "kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets" -m mark --mark 0x8000/0x8000 -j DROP
-A KUBE-FIREWALL ! -s 127.0.0.0/8 -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m comment --comment "block incoming localnet connections" -m conntrack ! --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED,DNAT -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.98.240.243/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "eramba-2/eramba-web2:http has no endpoints" -m tcp --dport 8080 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.100.17.120/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "eramba-1/eramba-web:http has no endpoints" -m tcp --dport 8080 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

I'm sure I'm unaware of other ways where I can access the individual Application instances, so please advice if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Endpoints: <none>` is an indication your Service is configured wrong; its selector doesn't match any of the Pods.  If you look at the Service, it looks for

```yaml
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: eramba-web
```

But if you look at the Deployment, it generates Pods with different labels

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eramba-web # not app.kubernetes.io/name: ...
```

I'd consistently use the `app.kubernetes.io/name` format everywhere.  You will have to delete and recreate the Deployment to change its `selector:` value to match.